# fteching jSON causing application to crash ?? What should I have to do resolve it.I want to store response in userObj.movie_rating

Tags: json, ios7, parse-platform, nsdictionary

json is:

```
{
    "Title":"Kick", "Year":"2009", "Rated":"N/A", "Released":"08 May 2009",
    "Runtime":"N/A", "Genre":"Comedy, Romance, Thriller", "Director":"Reddy Surender",
    "Writer":"Abburi Ravi (dialogue), Reddy Surender (screenplay), Vakkantham Vamsi (story)",
    "Actors":"Ravi Teja, Ileana, Shaam, Ali", 
    "Plot":"A guy with an abnormal lifestyle tries to find thrill and pleasure in every work he does and finally becomes a thief.",
    "Language":"Telugu", "Country":"India", "Awards":"1 nomination.",
    "Poster":"N/A","Metascore":"N/A",
    "imdbRating":"7.6",
    "imdbVotes":"736", 
    "imdvid":"tt1579592", 
    "Type":"movie", 
    "Response":"True"
}
```

The Code is:

```
-(void)parseData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseString %@",responseString);

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                    options:(kNilOptions)
                                                      error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json data == %@", json);

    NSMutableArray *response =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++)
    {
        response = [json valueForKey:@"imdbRating"];
        User * userObj = [[User alloc]init];
        userObj.movieRating = [json valueForKey:@"imdbRating"];
        [response addObject:userObj];     
    }

    [delegate getIMDBMovie_Rating:response];
}
```

How to save data in bussiness model object for key imdbRating

Comment: What's the error? Which line?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
-(void)parseData:(NSData *)data
{

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseString %@",responseString);

    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:(kNilOptions) error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json data == %@", json);

    NSMutableArray *response =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSArray *aArray = [json valueForKey:@"imbdRating"];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in aArray)
    {

       /* Create a initWithData method in your User Model class and pass the dictionary object to it like,
        - (id) initWithData:(NSDictionary *) jsonDictionary
        {
           self=[super init];

            if(self)
            {
                self.movieRating =[json valueForKey:@"imdbRating"];
            } */
        User * userObj = [[User alloc]initWithData:dictionary];
        [response addObject:userObj];
    }

    [delegate getIMDBMovie_Rating:response];

}
```

Comment: Your solution is not quite correct: `[json valueForKey:@"imbdRating"]` returns a `NSString`, not an `NSMutableArray`. Especially, with the provided options in `JSONObjectWithData`, all JSON elements are _immutable_ anyway. Furthermore, retrieving an object with `valueForKey:` isn't preferable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The Json you specified is not an array. This is an `NSDictionary` object. Also as this is a NSDictionary you don't need to use for loop.

Second thing you are doing wrong with your `response` variable.

you did:

```
response = [json valueForKey:@"imdbRating"];
User * userObj = [[User alloc]init];
userObj.movieRating = [json valueForKey:@"imdbRating"];
[response addObject:userObj];
```

here `response` variable is not an array even though you allocated it as `NSMutableArray` earlier. As you assign new value in `response` in the line: `response = [json valueForKey:@"imdbRating"];`

your variable type will be either `NSNumber` or `NSString` based on the type of `[json valueForKey:@"imdbRating"]`.

So remove the line `response = [json valueForKey:@"imdbRating"];` and it will work.

By doing this you will hv an array of `User` objects containing imdbRatings.

**UPDATE**

According to your comment your code has:

```
-(void)getIMDBMovie_Rating:(NSMutableArray*)retrievedData { 
     if (retrievedData.count > 0) 
     { 
         userObj = [retrievedData objectAtIndex:0];              
         NSLog(@"%@is the value",retrievedData);                                       
         iMDB_MovieRatingLabel.text=userObj.movieRating; 
     }
}
```

Problem is in your `getIMDBMovie_Rating`. as your method is accepting NSMutableArray as parameter. But when you supply value for your method is NSDictionay `[delegate getIMDBMovie_Rating:response];` (you can check by `NSLog(@"%@", [response class]);`).

So in your `getIMDBMovie_Rating` method you are accessing `[retrievedData objectAtIndex:0];`. objectAtIndex is not available with NSDictionay that's why your app get crash.

Comment: i have done it like this :
-(void)parseData:(NSData *)data
{
    
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:(kNilOptions) error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json data == %@", json); 
    User * userObj = [[User alloc]init];
    userObj.movieRating = [json valueForKey:@"imdbRating"];
    [delegate getIMDBMovie_Rating:json];
}
But app still crashes[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:] and causes error.will you please send me the proper code to resolve it

Comment: Make your json variable to NSDictionary type first. and can you plz edit your question and add `[delegate getIMDBMovie_Rating:json]` method defination?

Comment: As of I understand is the issue is in `getIMDBMovie_Rating:` method.

Comment: this is a custom delegate to display respose vlue on uiLabel as:

-(void)getIMDBMovie_Rating:(NSMutableArray*)retrievedData

{
    if (retrievedData.count > 0)

    {
        userObj = [retrievedData objectAtIndex:0];
        
        NSLog(@"%@is the value",retrievedData);

        iMDB_MovieRatingLabel.text=userObj.movieRating;

    }
}

Comment: no kapil there is no problem in getIMDBMovie_Rating method , debugger is showing that URL is properly hit and the response is not properly managed to save in nsdictionary

Comment: Thanks for discuusions

Comment: @KapilChoubisa One improvement to your solution is to use `objectForKey:` instead `valueForKey:` (and giving a pointer where the differences are explained), or suggest alternatively the "short hand subscript accessor" for `NSDictionary`: `id value = json[@"imdbRating"]`